# How can I update react state using axios(to get json data) and redux(to update state)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-proptypes

I am trying to update the value of state of react using redux. To get the data I am using axios, but the data us not being returned and updated. When I check the state using redux tool the state is still empty list of initialState.

Here is the from src/action/feedbacks.js. Here axios is used to return the data in json format

```
import axios from "axios";

import { GET_FEEDBACKS } from "./types";

export const getFeedbacks = () => dispatch => {
  console.log(axios.get("/api/feedbacks/").res.data);
  axios
    .get("/api/feedbacks/")
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FEEDBACKS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

This code is from src/reducers/feedbacks.js.

```
import { GET_FEEDBACKS } from "../actions/types.js";

const initialState = {
  feedbacks: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_FEEDBACKS:
      return {
        ...state,
        feedbacks: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This code is from src/components/feedbacks/Feedbacks.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { getFeedbacks } from "../../actions/feedbacks";

export class Feedbacks extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    feedbacks: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  ComponentDidMount() {
    this.props.getFeedbacks();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //some return code
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  feedbacks: state.feedbacks.feedbacks
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getFeedbacks }
)(Feedbacks);
```

Comment: The function is called `componentDidMount`, not `ComponentDidMount`. Simple debugging would show that your action is not being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get this update on [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or do this with hooks.

Try something like this:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import {getFeedbacks} from "../../actions/feedbacks";

export const Feedbacks = props => {
    const {feedbacks, getFeedbacks} = props

    useEffect(() => {
        getFeedbacks();
    }, [])

    return (
       //some return code
    )
}

Feedbacks.propTypes = {
    feedbacks: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    feedbacks: state.feedbacks.feedbacks
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {getFeedbacks}
)(Feedbacks);
```

When redux update, this component receive the json of `feedbacks`, so when mounting this, maybe you should check if `feedbacks` has data or is empty before manipulate it.